# WebAPI and angular services: standard replies for UPDATE and DELETE requests

Tags: angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

in my REST service I have update and delete parts. 
According to http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations, UPDATE operation should reply as bool and DELETE operation sends empty reply.

Now, I have Angular $resource that is attached to the service. I have following questions:

- What sort of REST replies that $resource expects from server for UPDATE and DELETE? Is there any standard?
- If server just replied not an object/array but simply boolean value, such as "true", how do I configure angular resource to accept it, and how I can reach it later on client side?

I have noted that angular docs in my posession does not give any particularities about how typical responce should look like, some sort of best practice.

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your link, they only returned bool for the model which is not what your AngularJS application will see. What matters is what the controller returns. It is good practice to return a HTTP status. With HTTP status in the response header, you do not need a bool as the header is enough to indicate if the operation succeeded or failed. Some times, you may want to return the newly updated resource as well.

For UPDATE operation, you can return code 200 (`HttpStatusCode.OK`) when you simply updated a resource or code 201 (`HttpStatusCode.Created`) when you created a new resource (Many use POST for the latter). You may also add the created resource to the response. Depending on your application, this may not be necessary.

For DELETE operation, it is fine to simply return 200 when the resource has been deleted or some other code (e.g. 404 (`HttpStatusCode.NotFound`)) when the operation could not be completed.

[RESTful HTTP in practice](http://www.infoq.com/articles/designing-restful-http-apps-roth)

In your AngularJS application, you can access the response to each operation in the success/error callback of `$resource`. The HTTP status code would be in the response header.

[AngularJS $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)